# Помогите сверстать селектор выбора языка!

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

не могу понять как правильно сверстать вот такую штуку, помогите пожалуйста. Пробовал по разному уже, и везде упирался во что-то.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Требуется сверстать такой переключатель язык. Помгите

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу. Нажмите кнопку Править под вопросом и в редакторе вопроса нажмите CTRL+M, вставьте там ваш код по нужным секциям, обязательно нажмите кнопку "Привести в порядок", нажмите на "Запустить". Убедитесь, что всё отображается как надо и нет других ошибок, кроме тех, о которых вы спрашиваете

Answer (score 3):

Чисто визуальная составляющая может быть реализована следующим образом:

```css
body { background: #000; }

.lang {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  height: 60px; width: 80px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 2px #fff;
}
.lang:hover { height: max-content; }

input[name="lang"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

label {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 60px;
}
input:checked + label { order: -1; }
```

```html
<div class="lang">
  <input name="lang" type="radio" id="lang_ru" checked><label for="lang_ru"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/offices/2x/russian-federation.png" alt="Русский"></label>
  <input name="lang" type="radio" id="lang_en"><label for="lang_en"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/offices/2x/great-britain.png" alt="English"></label>
  <input name="lang" type="radio" id="lang_cn"><label for="lang_cn"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/offices/2x/china.png" alt="中国人"></label>
</div>
```

*"The trouble of our time are ignoramuses, lazy and boors."*